# "this" onerror in an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, this, onerror

Let's say I have an iframe and that this iframe contains some JavaScript:

```
function triggerError() {
    throw "error";
}

window.onerror = function() {
    alert('error detected, initial iframe');
}
```

Let's also say that from the root window I have a reference to this iframe called "win". I can trigger the alert by calling `win.triggerError()`.

However, if I try to overwrite the error function from the outside, it will not work.

```
win.onerror = function () {
    alert('error detected, set from parent window');    
};
```

win.onerror *appears* to change if checked externally, although checking the value of onerror from inside of the iframe's window shows that the original function is still there.

However, I've found that this works:

```
win.test = function () {
    this.onerror = function () {
        alert('error detected, set using test()');  
    };  
};

win.test();
```

Why is this? Is this a *this*/scoping issue, or a browser-related issue?

Note: I am using IE9 with Quirks mode, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

1) I suppose the general problem is not browser-specific, but due to security reasons. If the IFRAME is not on the same domain, the infamous CORS considerations come into play. That's why changing the onerror from outside is not allowed.

2) If the pages are indeed on different domains, the latter approach though looks like an IE specific security breach )

Basically, when the script inside the iframe rules its own onerror, it is completely allowed in any case. The idea behind this is that if you provide such a function in your iframe code, it means you believe it to be secure for your purposes. But obviously you should not be able to inject such a function from outside.

3) If you use local file::// pages for testing, it's quite a mess in IE and everything is possible. I would advice not to use it at all even during development phase, it's better to set up a simple local NGINX server.

PS: If your pages are on the same domain, then onerror of the child IFRAME should be changeable. So in this case it's an IE issue.